# Zooqle.com clicking on desired search result

Tags: python, selenium

I was wondering if someone could help

I am trying to click on the search result that matches the text of the search:

IE: Searched Text: "The Fifth Element" 
    Click on he Result with "The Fifth Element" in it

with this code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\littl\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://zooqle.com/")

popup1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="anp2-wrapper"]/div/div/div[1]')
popup1.click()

searchbar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputSearchTop"]')
searchbar.send_keys("The Fifth Element")

time.sleep(2)

searchbar.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "The Fifth Element")]').click()
```

but am getting the error that this element is not interactive

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait` and following `xpath`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\littl\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://zooqle.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="anp2-wrapper"]//div[text()="NO THANKS"]'))).click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]'))).send_keys("The Fifth Element")
element=wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-qs"]//p[@class="tt-wrap tt-suggestion tt-selectable"]//span[text()="The Fifth Element"]')))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]